# Is it advisable to use 'unstable' angularjs libraries?

Tags: angularjs

The extensive documentation on latest 1.2.0 rc series suggests that Angular team is promoting it.

The series is much more modular in which its asking to download libraries for routing, animation etc. I'm concerned if this would make code more prone to breaking especially since Angularjs itself is branding these libraries as 'unstable'.

I'm new to angularjs, people who's used 'unstable versions' previously, can help notify the pitfalls, one should take care of, or simply adhere to the latest stable library of 1.0.8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS as I understand has extensive suite of tests that it runs for each of its build, so the chances of bugs are low. Also `RC` means close to production version :)

Said that the bigger issue here could be your dependency on features\api which may change and could be considered as breaking changes. `Animation` is one such example which has changed a lot from `1.1.5` to `1.2.0`. You dependency on any of those feature would require some rewrite when you plan to upgrade the framework.  But i guess this is true for any framework\library

Comment: Great answer.  Just to summarize, it's not unstable as in buggy, it's unstable in terms of API.  Having said that, there's a lot of great improvements in 1.1 and now 1.2 that you're likely gonna want ($resource and $animate for examples).